# Reducing iOS app size - Are <imagename>@2x.png images redundant?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, retina-display, iphone-5

I am trying to reduce the size (30+ MB) of my binary submission, and I sense that images acquire a sizable (>26 MB) part.

I also observed that if I remove retina images (`@2x.png`), iOS gracefully replaces them with 4-inch retina (`-568h@2x.png`) versions.

Are the retina images really redundant if I supply `-568h@2x.png` versions?

**P.S.**

Not that one image makes much of a difference, but if the answer is a Yes, does this also apply for `default.png`?

Comment: Can you give a list of some of the images you have (many `-568h@2x.png` images ?)

Comment: Yes, I do have them - about 20 of them. For each size, and for each device.

Comment: Are they background images?

Comment: Few of them are, but not all. Most of them are for buttons, others for views that partially cover the screen.

Comment: And these buttons and views are different sizes on iPhone 5 compared to iPhone 4 ?

Comment: Not really, but I size them up based on the image sizes, because just didn't think about it earlier. Also, I would also like to expand this question for ipad and ipad retina (I mean, image@2x.png can serve for image.png, isn't it?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `image@2x` can be used as a stand in for `image`, but not the other way around (because they wouldn't look good). The side effect of doing this is that more memory will be used and on non-retina devices that could cause a problem. If you aren't supporting non-retina devices then you don't need any `image`s.

Generally speaking you shouldn't have many `image-568h@2x` images other than the `Default` and other background images. Most of your content images will be the same size no matter what the screen size is. You do not need differently named images for a button of the same size on multiple different screen sizes.

Answer (score 2):

@2x images are for retina devices. They look much crisper and clean on retina devices (e.g. iPad3, iPhone 5) as compared to their non-retina counterpart images. Here are few suggestions to reduce size of your binary.

1) For background images check if they are really needed. If they are simple solid color images you can simply set the backgroundColor of the UIView.

2) Whenever possible use 9 patch (also called 9 scale) images for button or view backgrounds. They are generally 1 px wide images and you can use below method of UIImage to use them

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode
```

Comment: Can you list any tutorial that does this? I am not sure how this can replace real graphics?

Comment: Good point about the image resizing for buttons (though they might well be bigger than 1px to get the edges / corners looking right).

Comment: @Wain yes generally > 1 px but 1 px images are also possible.

Comment: @NiravBhatt there is so much help available on internet regarding 9-scale images, just do a google search. I remember one Apple document on it but not able to find it right now.